# Recorrido de una matriz y selección de los menores en cada fila en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos

estoy tratando con el siguiente problema:

Dada una matriz, por ejemplo:

```
array = [[7, 3, 7, 2],
       [9, 9, 4, 1],
       [9, 4, 8, 1],
       [3, 4, 8, 4]]
```

Quiero seleccionar de cada fila, el menor número, de forma que no pueda seleccionar dos números de filas distintas que estén en la misma columna. Por ejemplo, en este caso, al seleccionar de la primera fila el 2, en la segunda fila ya no podría seleccionar el 1 , ya que coinciden las columnas.

Una idea de algoritmo que he pensando es la siguiente:

1. Miro la primera fila y cojo el menor número.
2. Miro la segunda fila y cojo el más bajo. Si este coincide con la columna escogida anteriormente, cojo el segundo más bajo.
3. Así hasta que acabo de recorrer todas las filas de la matriz.

Tengo esta idea pero no consigo implementarla, si alguien pudiese ayudarme.

***Edición:***

Alguien me ha aconsejado partir de la idea más básica, que sería guardar el mínimo de cada fila sin importar la condición de la columna:

```
lis = []
p = []
for fila in array:
    a = fila.index(min(fila))
    if a not in p:
        lis.append(fila[a])
        p.append(a)
    else:
        print(fila)
```

Con a, encuentro el índice del número más pequeño de una fila. Añado este índice en un vector en el que guardo posiciones y añado en otra lista el valor de este número.

Después, compruebo si en el vector de posiciones está el siguiente índice del número más pequeño. Esto es una forma de comprobar que no está escogiendo la misma columna.

Ahora, si se cumple esta condición, no se como seleccionar el mínimo de esa fila excluyendo el valor en la posición repetida.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Deberías añadir a la pregunta el código con lo que has intentado hasta el momento para ver dónde te equivocas.

Comment: Sugerencia: parte por algo simple, como seleccionar el menor elemento de cada fila sin importar la columna. Luego que tengas eso, intenta imponer la condición de columnas distintas. Cuando tengas algo de código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo.

Comment: Otra idea: copia los datos a otra matriz auxiliar porque la vamos a modificar. Busca el minimo en la primera fila, y rellena toda la columna en que aparezca con un número muy grande (p.ej. el máximo de toda la matriz, más 1). Luego busca el mínimo en la segunda fila y repite, etc.

Comment: Ya he añadido código como pedisteis :)

Comment: @PicaPython, como te has dado cuenta, una buena pregunta consigue respuestas rápidamente, recuerda siempre incluir tu código y la información completa. Saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La pregunta que planteas parece un ejercicio de clase, por lo que no sé si es correcto darte la solución completa en forma de código.

Te voy a dar una idea, y una implementación que usa `numpy` para que veas que funciona. Te queda la tarea de traducir esa implementación a python "normal" (que no use numpy). Puedes preguntar de nuevo si te vuelves a atascar.

### La idea

Tu planteamiento inicial parece bueno, pero se complica cuando quieres buscar en "el resto de la fila" (sin tener en cuenta los índices ya aparecidos). Tendrías quizás que eliminar de la fila todos los elementos que estén en los índices ya aparecidos y quedarte con el mínimo de la lista resultante.

Otra idea que creo que puede ser más simple es que, una vez has encontrado el mínimo en una fila y el índice que ocupa, escribas en todas las filas en esa posición un número grande (mayor que cualquiera de los que tenga la matriz).

De ese modo, cuando vayas a buscar el mínimo en la lista siguiente, el que estaba en esa posición ya no podrá salir, pues lo has cambiado por un valor grande que será necesariamente mayor que los que quedaban en la fila. Así que el mínimo será uno de los otros.

Por ejemplo, tu matriz inicial es esta:

```
[[7, 3, 7, 2],
 [9, 9, 4, 1],
 [9, 4, 8, 1],
 [3, 4, 8, 4]]
```

y en ella el número más alto es el 9. Así que tras encontrar el mínimo de la primera fila (que es 2) y ver que está en el índice 3, cambiamos todos los elementos que ocupaban ese índice por 9+1. Y queda ahora así:

```
[[7, 3, 7, 10],
 [9, 9, 4, 10],
 [9, 4, 8, 10],
 [3, 4, 8, 10]]
```

De ese modo al pasar a la segunda fila el mínimo ahora ya no puede ser el que estaba en el índice 3, y de hecho vemos que sale el 4 (índice 2) por lo que volverías a rellenar con 10 los elementos en la tercera columna, etc.

### Implementación con numpy (prueba de concepto)

```
import numpy as np
array = [[7, 3, 7, 2],
         [9, 9, 4, 1],
         [9, 4, 8, 1],
         [3, 4, 8, 4]]
array = np.array(array)

aux = array.copy()                 # Para no modificar la matriz original
grande = aux.max().max() + 1       # numero "muy grande"
for fila in aux:
   menor = fila.min()
   indice = fila.argmin()
   aux[:,indice] = grande    # Rellenar columna elegida
   print(menor)
```

Al ejecutarlo sale lo siguiente:

```
2
4
4
3
```

Comment: Hola. Finalmente conseguí solucionar el problema. Te adjunto mi solución:

`lis = []

p = []
for fila in array:
    a = fila.index(min(fila))
    if a not in p:
        lis.append(fila[a])
        p.append(a)
    else:
        fila[a] = 100
        b = fila.index(min(fila))
        lis.append(fila[b])
        p.append(b)
            

print(p,lis)`

Answer (score 1):

Una solución sencilla, sin librerías adicionales:

```
array = [[7, 3, 7, 2],
       [9, 9, 4, 1],
       [9, 4, 8, 1],
       [3, 4, 8, 4]]

# Indices contiene todas las columnas validas para busqueda
indices = [i for i in range(len(array))]

for fila in array:
    # Seleccionar solo los valores en columnas disponibles.
    valores_a_examinar = [(fila[i], i) for i in indices]
    # Ordenar los valores para obtener el menor en formato (valor, indice)
    min_tupla = sorted(valores_a_examinar, key=lambda tupla: tupla[0])[0]
    # Eliminar el indice la columna seleccionada, para no usarla de nuevo
    del indices[min_tupla[1]]
    # Imprimir
    print(fila, "minimo=", min_tupla[0], "en columna=", min_tupla[1])
```

**Análisis**

Primero creamos una lista con los índices de columna "disponibles" para participar en la búsqueda del menor elemento por fila. A medida que recorramos el arreglo, iremos eliminando columnas de esta lista:

```
# Indices contiene todas las columnas validas para busqueda
indices = [i for i in range(len(array))]
```

Luego recorremos las filas y en cada una de ellas formamos una lista de tuplas. Cada tupla contiene el valor de la columna y el indice correspondiente:

```
for fila in array:
    # Seleccionar solo los valores en columnas disponibles.
    valores_a_examinar = [(fila[i], i) for i in indices]
```

Con esto nos saltamos todas las columnas ya "seleccionadas" previamente.

Para obtener el menor valor, ordeno esta lista de tuplas en función de su primer elemento y luego extraigo el primer elemento de la lista retornada

```
# Ordenar los valores para obtener el menor en formato (valor, indice)
min_tupla = sorted(valores_a_examinar, key=lambda tupla: tupla[0])[0]
```

Con esto tengo el primer valor y el indice donde lo encontre. Procedo entonces a eliminar este indice de la lista disponible:

```
# Eliminar el indice la columna seleccionada, para no usarla de nuevo
del indices[min_tupla[1]]
```

y luego sólo me queda imprimir:

```
# Imprimir
print(fila, "minimo=", min_tupla[0], "en columna=", min_tupla[1])
```

Ejecutando lo anterior, produce:

```
[7, 3, 7, 2] minimo= 2 en columna= 3
[9, 9, 4, 1] minimo= 4 en columna= 2
[9, 4, 8, 1] minimo= 4 en columna= 1
[3, 4, 8, 4] minimo= 3 en columna= 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Por que no usar min en lugar de sorted?